Disabling/hiding the Tabulator row hover highlighter?
Trying to disable the row highlighter when user hovers a row since it serves no purpose in my app and is distracting.
Tried using:
background-color: transparent;

in the style for
.tabulator .tabulator-row:hover

and that halfway works but on rows with the alternate color then the alternate color disappears.
Is there a simple way to accomplish this?  Or even a difficult way?
I don't really understand why there isn't a built-in property to control this but that's just a gripe.

You can try setting odd and even row hover styles to match their non hover styles. Ex. .tabulator-row-odd:hover { background-color: #fff !important; }  .tabulator-row-even:hover { background-color: #efefef !important;}
